# how to know of the number of real roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $ax^4 +bx^3 +cx^3 +dx + e = 0$ with $a,b,c,d,e\in\mathbb R$. I would like to know, how can I determine the condition for the polynomial to have exactly three distinct real solutions.
one has to be a double root, or is there any other possibility.

I need help please.

Thanks

Comment: Are there any restrictions? In particular, are $a,b,c,d,e$ real numbers?

Comment: they are real no.s

Comment: That is an extremely important assumption. Please edit it into your question.

Comment: If with "3 distinct roots" you mean the roots to be 3 distinct numbers `a, b, c` and one of them a double root, then it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending what you mean, if the equation has a double root eg $x^2(x+1)(x-1)=0$ it can have three distinct real roots, but we've counted one twice.

So there are two conditions:

(i) One double root
(ii) The other two roots are real and distinct

Comment: You can computationally figure this out by computing the GCD of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$. If there is a single double root, $r$, then the gcd should be $x-r$. Then factor out $(x-r)^2$ and determine if the resulting quadratic has real roots.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The complex conjugate root theorem (for polynomials with real coefficients) states that complex roots occur in conjugate pairs.

**Hint:** If we have 3 distinct real roots to a degree 4 equations, how many complex roots do we have?

Answer (score 1):

Usually roots are counted according to multiplicity of roots. So, in my humble opinion, it is assumed that first coefficient is zero: $a=0$. Thus we get cubic equation and there are conditions on discriminant for cubic equation such that it has 3 roots. See, for instance, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function

Answer (score 0):

Complex roots(in a polynomial with real coefficients) occur in pairs so the no. of real roots can be either $2$ or $4$

If there are 3 distinct real roots then the no. of real root(not necessarily distinct) is 4 hence there are no complex root.

Comment: How about $x(x-1)(x-2)^2$?

Comment: There is no complex root of this equation....

Comment: So? It's a degree $4$ polynomial with three distinct real roots.

Comment: one of the root has multiplicity 2 so it makes the equation to have 4 real roots and 3 $\huge{distinct}$ real roots

Comment: Which is what the OP asked: *"polynomial to have exactly **three distinct** real solutions"*

Comment: I had missed the point. But I think my answer makes sense.